# Catch2 UnorderedEquals correct usage

Tags: catch2

I am new to Catch2 and have one question on the UnorderedEquals vector matcher. Here is the code:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"

using namespace Catch::Matchers;

TEST_CASE("Test Unordered Equals") {
    std::vector<char> actual = {'a', 'b'};
    std::vector<char> expected = {'c', 'b'};

    CHECK_THAT(actual, UnorderedEquals(expected));
}
```

This test is passed under the Clion IDE with MinGW. What was wrong with the testing code? So what is the UnorderedEquals usage? Thanks.
[test result snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzvSG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug fixed in v2.4.1
[release note of 2.4.1](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/releases/tag/v2.4.1)